# La función se ejecuta una vez sola

Tags: jquery, function, ejecutar

Estoy realizando una función que sirve para que cuando hagas click en el elemento `.articulo`, el contenido del elemento `.articulos` se modifique y en esa modificación se añaden dos botones `.return` que sirven para volver al estado anterior del elemento `.articulos`.
La función funciona perfectamente, hace todo lo que tiene que hacer debidamente, no obstante, solo me sirve para hacer un click. Es decir:

1. Hago click en `.articulo`
2. Se despliega el nuevo contenido, modificándose el elemento `.articulos`
3. Hago click en `.return` y vuelvo a tener el contenido que tenía antes del paso 1
4. Vuelvo a hacer click en `.articulo` **y no se me despliega el nuevo contenido** --> ESTE ES EL PROBLEMA

EL navegador no me muestra ningún mensaje de error, por lo que creo que el problema radica en la llamada a la función. Aún así, no he conseguido encontrar el problema.

Adjunto código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.articulo').click(function() {
    abrirArticulo();
  });
});

function abrirArticulo() {
  console.log('hagoClick');
  var titulo = $('.articulo .inverter h3').html();
  var tema = $('.articulo .inverter p').html();
  var imagen = 'img/prueba.png';
  var contenido = $('.texto').html();

  var antiguoContenido = $('.articulos').html();
  var nuevoCont = '';
  nuevoCont +=
    '<h1>' +
    titulo +
    '</h1>' +
    '<h3>' +
    tema +
    '</h3>' +
    '<div> <img class="imagenArt" src=" ' +
    imagen +
    '" alt="Imagen en el otro img" /></div>' +
    '<div>' +
    contenido +
    '</div>';

  $('.articulos').html(nuevoCont);
  $('.articulos').css({
    'background-color': 'white',
    'margin-top': '1%',
    padding: '2%',
    'border-radius': '1em'
  });

  $('.articulos').before("<div class='return'>Volver</div>");
  $('.articulos').after(
    "<div class='return' style='margin-top: 2%'>Volver</div>"
  );

  $('.return').click(function() {
    $('.articulos').html(antiguoContenido);
    $('.articulos').css({
      'background-color': '',
      padding: '0',
      'border-radius': '0',
      'margin-top': '0'
    });

    $('.return').remove();
  });

  $('.return').css({
    'background-color': 'rgb(238, 208, 124)',
    padding: '1%',
    width: '10%',
    'text-align': 'center'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="articulos" id="cuerpo">
  <div class="articulo">
    <div class="artModoMovil">
      <div class="inverter">
        <h3>Título de articulo<small> Datos de publicación</small></h3>
        <p>Temática</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inverterImg">
        <img class="imagenArt" src="img/prueba.png" alt="Esto es una imagen de prueba">
      </div>
      <div class="texto">
        Esto es texto
        Esto es texto
        Esto es texto
        Esto es texto
        Esto es texto
        Esto es texto
        Esto es texto
        Esto es texto
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Leer más</a> <br>
    <small>Aquí va el autor</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opinión personal, pero creo que el manipular el html de esa forma dentro de una función js está muy mal. Los cambios que estás haciendo son netamente estéticos y perfectamente podrías hacerlo manteniendo ambas vistas en el html y cambiando su propiedad de estilo `display` con js, dependiendo si quieres mostrarlo u ocultarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes utilizar `click()`, necesitas usar `on()` asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    

    $(".articulos").on('click', '.articulo', function(){
        abrirArticulo();
    });

    //FUNCIONES PARA EL MODO MOVIL

    
});

function abrirArticulo() {
    console.log("hagoClick");
    var titulo = $(".articulo .inverter h3").html();
    var tema = $(".articulo .inverter p").html();
    var imagen = "img/prueba.png";
    var contenido = $(".texto").html();

    var antiguoContenido = $(".articulos").html();
    var nuevoCont = "";
    nuevoCont += "<h1>" + titulo + "</h1>" +
            "<h3>" + tema + "</h3>" +
            '<div> <img class="imagenArt" src=" ' + imagen + '" alt="Imagen en el otro img"/></div>' +
            "<div>" + contenido + "</div>";

    $(".articulos").html(nuevoCont);
    $(".articulos").css({
        "background-color": "white",
        "margin-top": "1%",
        "padding": "2%",
        "border-radius": "1em"
    });

    $(".articulos").before("<div class='return'>Volver</div>");
    $(".articulos").after("<div class='return' style='margin-top: 2%'>Volver</div>");

    $(".return").click(function () {
        $(".articulos").html(antiguoContenido);
        ;
        $(".articulos").css({
            "background-color": "",
            "padding": "0",
            "border-radius": "0",
            "margin-top": "0"
        });

        $(".return").remove();
    });

    $(".return").css({
        "background-color": "rgb(238, 208, 124)",
        "padding": "1%",
        "width": "10%",
        "text-align": "center"
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="articulos" id="cuerpo">
                        <div class="articulo">
                        <div class="artModoMovil">
                            <div class="inverter">
                                <h3>Título de articulo<small> Datos de publicación</small></h3>
                                <p>Temática</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inverterImg">
                                <img class="imagenArt" src="img/prueba.png" alt="Esto es una imagen de prueba">
                            </div>
                            <div class="texto">
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">Leer más</a> <br>
                        <small>Aquí va el autor</small>
                    </div>
                   </div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me podrías explicar el uso del on() ??

Comment: Sirve para declarar handlers a elementos dinamicos, como en tu caso.